# Distributed compilation of CUDA C application (like distcc, but with support for nvcc compiler)

Tags: compilation, cuda, gpgpu, distcc

Is there a tool to speed up and distribute compilation of GPGPU programs using CUDA C (where **`nvcc` compiler** is part of compilation chain), i.e. something like `distcc` + `ccache` (or derivatives and wrappers like distcc-pump, ccontrol, Icecream (IceCC) or DMUCS) for C / C++ and GCC compiler?

Or alternatively is it possible to configure distcc for use with nvcc?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think it's at all straightforward to make distcc work with non-gcc compilers.  It's not impossible, just a nuisance because you have to go modify the distcc implementation to understand the new compiler's options, as mentioned on the [distcc FAQ](http://distcc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/web/faq.html).

An alternative is to use something like Electric Make, which solves the same problem (accelerating builds) in roughly the same way (distribution and parallelization), but at the level of the build tool instead of the compiler.  That means that it's completely indifferent to the particular compiler that you use.  You can get a free version from http://www.electric-cloud.com/eade.

*Disclaimer: I am the Chief Architect of Electric Make*

Comment: When I try to download ElectricFlow/Make/whatever, it says 1.7 GB. Also, I don't see a Debian repository link anywhere, just a stand-alone download.

Comment: ElectricFlow is a different product.  The download for ElectricAccelerator Huddle, the free version of ElectricAccelerator which includes Electric Make, is only about 100MB on Linux.  No, there is no .deb package for it.